# Python, как отправить аудио телеграмм ботом?

Tags: python, telebot

Пишу телеграмм бота, суть которого в том, чтобы отправлять пользователю песни по его выбору.

Вот код, что я написал:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('MyToken')

keyboard1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
keyboard1.row('"Bad guy" - Billie Eilish', '"Вечная тема" - Alik')

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет! Ты написаk мне /start\n Выбери песню, что ты хочешь послушать', reply_markup = keyboard1)

@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def send_songs(message):
    if message.text == '"Bad guy" - Billie Eilish':
        audio = open(r'C:/Users/Alex Komissarov/Downloads/Billie Eilish - bad guy.mp3', 'rb')
        bot.send_chat_action(message.from_user.id, 'upload_audio')
        bot.send_audio(message.from_user.id, audio)
        audio.close()

bot.polling()
```

Проблема в том, что когда пользователь выбирает песню, бот пытается ее отправить, написано "отправка аудио сообщения", но в итоге отправка прекращается и ничего не присылается. Не могли бы вы подсказать, что можно сделать, чтобы все до конца работало и присылалось? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Возможно проблема с интернетом? У меня ваш код работает

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое, что сказали, возможно правда с интернетом проблема

Answer (score 1):

Так работает:

```
audio = open(r'/Users/filename.mp3', 'rb')
bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, audio)
audio.close()
```